# render simple HTML with react.cloneElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React.cloneElement() always require first parameter as react component which should be passed as children in props.

Is there are way to pass a simple HTML node as a children. Please refer the code below for better understanding of my issue:

Dialog.jsx (Common component):

```
 return (
            <div className="app-dialog-jsx" ref={(ele) => this.ele = ele}>
                {this.state.show && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                    contentStyle: {
                        height: 400,
                        overflowY: 'auto',
                        overflowX: 'hidden'
                    },
                    method1: this. method1,
                    method2: this. method2
                })}
            </div>
        );
```

now I can not pass:

```
<Dialog
  ref={(dialog)=>this.dialog=dialog}
  method1={()=>console.log(1)}
  method2 ={()=>console.log(1)}
>
  <h4>somethign</h4>
</Dialog>
```

H4 needs to be a react component otherwise it will not set the props in cloneElement. How can I send simple HTML here, any help?

Comment: whats the issue? it should work. check [**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/ysgxehdq/). let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: Can you please check here https://jsfiddle.net/pk1t65Lu/17/. I have modified

Comment: Yes, this should work.  <h4></h4> is a React Element when you use it inside JSX.

Comment: But test1 is not rendering the props. I want simple HTML to render the props. That is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detail about why [**your fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pk1t65Lu/17/) is not working as expected.

See the code here:

```
{this.props.show && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
    contentStyle: {
        color:'red'
    }
})}
```

Issue is in case of Custom Component like `CCC`,  `contentStyle` will get passed as props and you are using it like this:

```
style={this.props.contentStyle}
```

That means at the end style will be applied on div not contentStyle. But in case of `div`, `contentStyle` will get applied and that will not change anything because `div` expect `style` not `contentStyle`.

To solve your problem rename `contentStyle` to `style` at all the places.

Check this **[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/r86fcvbo/1/)**.

Comment: SO, do you mean to say, we can not pass custom props to the normal HTML? and it must be a valid attribute of HTML.

Comment: you can pass custom props, they will be available on element but how they will work? see in case of custom component your are using them `style={this.props.contentStyle}` means you are passing `contentStyle` but using `style` at the end, style will get applied, but in case of html who will do this job for you :)

Comment: check this fiddle, here we are passing `contentStyle` and at the end using `style` (check div). [**check fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/aqbwt67b/)

Comment: Thanks a ton for explaining. :)

Comment: hehe, explaining things like this in words, is very difficult, glad i did that :)

Answer (score 0):

**The best link that can describe the answer is here:**

> https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html

The unknown-prop warning will fire if you attempt to render a DOM element with a prop that is not recognized by React as a legal DOM attribute/property. You should ensure that your DOM elements do not have spurious props floating around.

To fix it we should split the props before rendering. like:

```
render(){
const {children, addCustomProps, ...props} = this.props;
  return(<div {...props}>{children}</div>);
}
```

To avoid the warning, we should pass only those props to the DOM , which can be recognized as a HTML attribute or React attribute like className.